# How to check array length with default value in mongoose

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongoose

When an array is declared in mongoose model it is creating a default array element with [0] by which the condition for array length fails .Can anyone suggest help.Thanks.

```
pepsi{
sales : [];
}
My code,

   if(vm.pepsi.sales && vm.pepsi.sales.length > 0){}
```

Comment: Please show your db schema

Comment: what do you mean with "the condition for array length fails"? what do you want to check? When I want to check if an array is empty I just use `!vm.pepsi.sales.length` if the array is empty (like in your example) the value of this expression will be true